# how to products list of the cart at Product details page

Tags: joomla2.5, virtuemart

I want to get the product list of cart in the Product details page. how to get it???
I think cart details are stored in a session.
How to use it on Product details page
i'm using Virtuemart 2.022a and Joomla 2.5.9

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
$cart = VirtueMartCart::getCart();

if(sizeof($cart->products){
 echo "<pre/>";
 print_r($cart->products);

}
```

Hope its help you..